# What is a discrete logarithmic assumption? How does it set up trustless proofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

A pending proposal of bulletproofs as a ZK proof for confidential transactions relies on Fiat-Shamir heuristic to be non-interactive by creating a digital signature on interactive proof of knowledge. As described in  ["Bulletproofs: Short Proofs for Confidential Transactions and More" [Bootle, Wuille, Maxwell et al]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf) it also relies on discrete logarithmic assumption to be a trustless proof (unlike SNARKs).

This led to my question above, what is a discrete logarithmic assumption and how does it set up trustless proofs? I'm not well-versed on this topic and would like to learn more about this, more specifically in its relation to setting up bulletproofs.